# Getting syntax error for Spring security with Jersey Rest API

Tags: json, spring, spring-security

I am doing authentication for REST Services.

So If user is unauthenticated then I want to send the user as "unauthenticated user" as repsonse in JSON format.

below is my code . I have set the content type as APPLICATION_JSON then I am getting the response as syntax error on postman tool. I can see the exact error in plainText or in Xml but not able to see the response in JSON.

Could anybody help me to get out from this issu please.

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String msg = authException.getMessage(); 
        response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + msg+ "\" }");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it in wrong way the method syntax in ServeletResponse class is:

**void setContentType(java.lang.String type)**

so it should be like this

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was really doing it in wrong way... Created the xmltype of pojo class and send response in JSON